# Function is not being called React native

Tags: react-native

I have a function called **setSTNo** and it's not being called. I tried so many times but couldn't figure out the error. Need assistant..

code

```
const  onRefresh = React.useCallback(async() => {
    setserviceTData([])
    fetch(`${API_URL}/v1/serviceTicket`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'apiKey': 'asdkhjfgsed34e',
            'deviceId': deviceId,
            'sessionId': sessionId

        },
    })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            if (!json.success ) {
                if (json.errorCode === 403) {
                    sessionExpire()
                }
            } else if(json.data){
                setserviceTData(json.data);
                console.log('Ticket Data',json.data);
                setSTNo();

            }
        }
        )
        .catch((error) => console.error(error))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false));
        
    }, [refreshing]);
    
    console.log("st No" , serviceTData)
```

The above console.log function is working properly. But I don't know why it's not calling the function & shows
`[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'serviceTData.id')]`
My function is below

```
   async function  setSTNo  (serviceTData)  {
    console.log("st No tryyy" )
       try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('STnumber', serviceTData.id);
        setLaststNumber(serviceTData.id);
        console.log("OLD st No" , LaststNumber);
       } catch (e){
        console.log("Error Part",e);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `setSTNo` is expecting a parameter `serviceTData` which you are not passing down to it.
I'm guessing the `serviceTData` is one of your useState items and you want to call the function `setSTNo` whenever the `serviceTData` value is updated.

If so,

1. You can remove the `serviceTData` from `async function  setSTNo  (serviceTData)` parameter list
2. Add a `useEffect` to listen for the changes in the `serviceTData` item and then call the function `setSTNo` whenever the `serviceTData` is updated.
3. remove the `setSTNo` function call from your API call then block.

```js
 async function  setSTNo  ()  {
   console.log("st No tryyy" )
   try {
     await AsyncStorage.setItem('STnumber', serviceTData.id);
     setLaststNumber(serviceTData.id);
     console.log("OLD st No" , LaststNumber);
   } catch (e){
     console.log("Error Part",e);
   }
 }
```

Then add a `useEffect` to listen to your `serviceTData` state.

```js
useEffect(() => {
 if(serviceTData)
   setSTNo();
},[serviceTData]);
```

assuming the initial state of `serviceTData` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

It appears your function `setSTN` needs an argument that you are not sending

Your code:

```js
} else if(json.data){
  setserviceTData(json.data);
  console.log('Ticket Data',json.data);
  setSTNo(); //TODO THIS NEEDS AN ARGUMENT <------------------
}
```

Comment: How to do that any suggestions?

Comment: You send in an argument by adding something between `()`

Comment: what should i add between `( )` ??